# plotting a fitted segmented linear model shows more break points than what is estimated

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, piecewise

I was helping a friend with segmented regressions today. We were trying to fit a piecewise regression with a breakpoints to see if it fits data better than a standard linear model.

I stumbled across a problem I cannot understand. When fitting a piecewise regression with a single breakpoint with the data provided, it does indeed fit a single breakpoint.

However, when you predict from the model it gives what looks like 2 breakpoints. When plotting the model using `plot.segmented()` this problem does not happen.

Anyone have any idea what is going on and how I can get the proper predictions (and standard errors etc)? Or what I am doing wrong in the code in general?

```
# load packages
library(segmented)

# make data
d <- data.frame(x = c(0, 3, 13, 18, 19, 19, 26, 26, 33, 40, 49, 51, 53, 67, 70, 88
),
                y = c(0, 3.56211608128595, 10.5214485148819, 3.66063708049802, 6.11000808621074, 
                      5.51520423804034, 7.73043895812661, 7.90691392857039, 6.59626527933846, 
                      10.4413913666936, 8.71673928545967, 9.93374157928462, 1.214860139929, 
                      3.32428882257746, 2.65223361387063, 3.25440939462105))

# fit normal linear regression and segmented regression
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x, d)
seg_lm <- segmented(lm1, ~ x)

slope(seg_lm)
#> $x
#>            Est.  St.Err. t value CI(95%).l   CI(95%).u
#> slope1  0.17185 0.094053  1.8271 -0.033079  0.37677000
#> slope2 -0.15753 0.071933 -2.1899 -0.314260 -0.00079718

# make predictions
preds <- data.frame(x = d$x, preds = predict(seg_lm))

# plot segmented fit
plot(seg_lm, res = TRUE)

# plot predictions
lines(preds$preds ~ preds$x, col = 'red')
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-27 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a pure plotting issue.

```
#Call: segmented.lm(obj = lm1, seg.Z = ~x)
#
#Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
#(Intercept)            x         U1.x  
#     2.7489       0.1712      -0.3291  
#
#Estimated Break-Point(s):
#psi1.x  
# 37.46
```

The break point is estimated to be at `x = 37.46`, which is not any of the sampling locations:

```
d$x
# [1]  0  3 13 18 19 19 26 26 33 40 49 51 53 67 70 88
```

If you make your plot with fitted values at those sampling locations,

```
preds <- data.frame(x = d$x, preds = predict(seg_lm))
lines(preds$preds ~ preds$x, col = 'red')
```

You won't visually see those fitted two segments join up at the break points, as `lines` just line up fitted values one by one. `plot.segmented` instead would watch for the break points and make the correct plot.

---

Try the following:

```
## the fitted model is piecewise linear between boundary points and break points
xp <- c(min(d$x), seg_lm$psi[, "Est."], max(d$x))
yp <- predict(seg_lm, newdata = data.frame(x = xp))

plot(d, col = 8, pch = 19)  ## observations
lines(xp, yp)  ## fitted model
points(d$x, seg_lm$fitted, pch = 19)  ## fitted values
abline(v = d$x, col = 8, lty = 2)  ## highlight sampling locations
```

[image: regression plot]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot specifically answer because I am not familiar to the software that you used. Nevertheless, I try with my own software (home made) and I got this :

Case of two connected segments :

[image]

This appears consistent with your result.

Case of two not connected segments :

[image]

Case of three connected segments :

[image]

One observe that the Mean Square Error is the smallest in case of two not connected segments, which is not surprising with so large scatter.

The case of three connected segments is interesting. The result is intermediate between the two others. The added segment makes an almost vertical link between the two other segments.

Well, this doesn't explain the strange result from the software that you use. I wonder why this software doesn't find the smallest MSE with three segments.

The prediction that you got (two large segments linked by a very small one) gives exactly the same MSE than without the small segment, insofar there is no experimental point related the small segment. One can find an infinity of equivalent solutions in adding "dummy" small segments insofar there is no experimental point related to them.

This is illustrated below, with a magnification of the "branching zone" to make it more lisible.

[image]

The 2 segments solution is (AC)+(CB).

The first 3 segments solution is (AD)+(DE)+(EB).

Another 3 segments solution is (AF)+(FG)+(GB).

Another 3 segments solution is (AH)+(HI)+(IB).

One can imagine many other...

All those solutions have the same MSE. So, they can be consider as equivalent on the statistical viewpoint with regard to the MSE as criteria.

Comment: No, my software doesn't looks  for break points at sampling locations. For example, in the case of two segments it gives the brake point (C) which is not at same abscissa as a sampling location. I took MSE as criteria of fitting as an example. Of course, many other criteria can be chosen. The question here is not to discuss the advantages and drawbacks of them. The question is to find an explanation of the strange behaviour observed by the OP.

Comment: Well, it possible that was only a plotting issue. Anyways, I found interesting to investigate what happens when we try a 3 segments fit in case of so large scatter.